# Protractor forces me to use browser.wait() even with async / await

Tags: angular, asynchronous, testing, jasmine, protractor

I'm getting into Protractor with native `async / await`. I don't understand why, in the following code, the line marked FOO passes, and why I have to do a `browser.wait()` before the line marked BAR will pass. If I remove `browser.wait()`, `expect(await loginHeading.isPresent()).toBe(true);` fails.

```
  it('choose to login with email', async function() {
    var loginButton = element(by.css('button'));
    var loginHeading = element(by.css('h3'));

    await loginButton.click();

    expect(await loginHeading.isPresent()).toBe(false); // FOO 
    await browser.wait(ec.visibilityOf(loginHeading), 1000, "Didn't load login header");
    expect(await loginHeading.isPresent()).toBe(true); // BAR
  });
```

I was under the impression that with `async / await`:

> browser.driver.wait() could be leveraged, but in Protractor this  functions is almost always unnecessary and can be avoided.

and

> Because Protractor is integrated in the Angular page state, it knows how to wait for the modal to appear before attempting to grab its text. No sleep or wait functions are needed.

(from [here](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/keep-your-promises-making-the-jump-from-selenium-to-protractor)).

The HTML for the button is very simple:

```
<button _ngcontent-c4="" class="btn btn-link" tabindex="0" ng-reflect-router-link="/account/login">
    Login with email
</button>
```

and `/account/login` is currently a simple component with an `h3`, and a `form`.

Is the `browser.wait()` reasonable and necessary here, and if so, why might that be? I'm happy to provide more information as necessary.

Comment: The question doesn't contain http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . There is no h3. It's unclear from the code above why it's expected that loginHeading will disappear and then appear, it doesn't make much sense. The problem is possibly in testing sequence. It should possibly be FOO, then click, then BAR, shouldn't it?

Comment: I can't do MCVE, because the site under test is currently still in a staging environment. But I can explain some more. `loginHeading` is not there originally, so with reference to your comment, it doesn't "disappear and then appear". After clicking on `loginButton`, the login form loads, and `loginHeader` is visible on that form(*), but apparently this doesn't happen not quickly enough. Let me know if I can provide more information.

(*) At least after some delay, which is imperceptible when browsing manually, and which `browser.wait()` seems to cope with.

Comment: Since MCVE is a requirement for problem-solving questions, this limits your possibilities to get a quality answer. Notice that MCVE is supposed to be *minimal*. It doesn't need the whole website. Did you try `FOO, then click, then BAR`? From what i understood, it doesn't make sense to test FOO *after* click.

Comment: I understand that, I did my best with the situation, and I appreciate your input. It doesn't make sense to click after `FOO`, because it's only after the click that the page with `loginHeading` actually loads. Put another way, the fact that `FOO` passes successfully is a Bad Thing! (The `FOO` line is just included for the purposes of the example, to show that it's necessary to `wait()` before `loginHeading` appear.)

Since posting, I have seen a few examples elsewhere using `await browser.wait()`, so perhaps I'm worrying about nothing and things are working as intended.